# React-Table fixed first row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, react-table

For starters, I've read [this post on using footers to fix the **last** row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49300597/reacttable-fixed-last-row), and also [this whole thread on ignoring top-row when sorting](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/373). In fact, I've read this thread several times over.

The threads are inconclusive about how to pin a top-row with react-table, but it is majorly important for my current project and I am seeking a solution. I created the following dummy table for help with this post:

```js
var ReactTable = ReactTable.default
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { firstName: 'joe', lastName: 'james', age: 18, status: 'real', visits: 14 },
        { firstName: 'tom', lastName: 'smith', age: 15, status: 'okay', visits: 24 },
        { firstName: 'tom', lastName: 'smith', age: 15, status: 'okay', visits: 24 },
        { firstName: 'tom', lastName: 'smith', age: 15, status: 'okay', visits: 24 },
        { firstName: 'tom', lastName: 'smith', age: 15, status: 'okay', visits: 24 }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "Name",
              columns: [
                {
                  width: '100',
                  Header: "First Name",
                  accessor: "firstName"
                },
                {
                  width: '100',
                  Header: "Last Name",
                  id: "lastName",
                  accessor: d => d.lastName
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: "Info",
              columns: [
                {
                  width: '100',
                  Header: "Age",
                  accessor: "age"
                },
                {
                  width: '100', 
                  Header: "Status",
                  accessor: "status"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: 'Stats',
              columns: [
                {
                  width: '100',
                  Header: "Visits",
                  accessor: "visits"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={5}
          showPagination={false}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

My goal currently is to create a fixed top-row **in any way possible**. Whether that is by (a) having the desired first-row data as the first object in the `data` array, or (b) having the desired first-row data in an object that's entirely separate from the `data` array, and coding that into the `header` of the column, or (c) some other approach, I don't mind if it's a bit hacky. *It appears at least* that there's no non-hacky approach this anyway... Feel free to create dummy data outside of `data` if you're able to pin it as the top row.

I'd like to style the fixed first-row differently from both the headers above it, and the rows below it. For the sake of this post, any getting simple styling on this row (e.g. a different background color) would be sufficient!

[This website here](https://www.cleaningtheglass.com/stats/team/2/lineups) (not built in React tho) has a great example of a fixed first row. When you sort the table, the `Totals` row remains on top. It is also styled separately from other rows.

Will bounty this post in 2 days, and any answers beforehand as well, as I could **really really really** use the help. Any thoughts / assistance is appreciated!

**Edit:** - another suggestion (although I dont know how it could be done) is to simply reposition React-Table's `Footer` as a first row, between the headers and the data. `Footer` is immune to sorting, although its on the bottom, not the top.

**Edit 2:** - per [this thread](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/1068), it is not possible to have a 3rd headerGroup, which would be needed since my websites tables already have a headerGroup and another main header.

Answer (score 2):

Add style option with height

```
style={{
    height: "200px"
}}
```

```js
var ReactTable = ReactTable.default
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { firstName: 'joe', lastName: 'james', age: 18, status: 'real', visits: 14 },
        { firstName: 'tom', lastName: 'smith', age: 15, status: 'okay', visits: 24 },
        { firstName: 'tom', lastName: 'smith', age: 15, status: 'okay', visits: 24 },
        { firstName: 'tom', lastName: 'smith', age: 15, status: 'okay', visits: 24 },
        { firstName: 'tom', lastName: 'smith', age: 15, status: 'okay', visits: 24 }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "Name",
              columns: [
                {
                  width: '100',
                  Header: "First Name",
                  accessor: "firstName"
                },
                {
                  width: '100',
                  Header: "Last Name",
                  id: "lastName",
                  accessor: d => d.lastName
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: "Info",
              columns: [
                {
                  width: '100',
                  Header: "Age",
                  accessor: "age"
                },
                {
                  width: '100', 
                  Header: "Status",
                  accessor: "status"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: 'Stats',
              columns: [
                {
                  width: '100',
                  Header: "Visits",
                  accessor: "visits"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={5}
          showPagination={false}
          style={{
               height: "200px"
          }}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Possibly i didn't explain the issue better. It's not that I need the header fixed-on-top when I scroll, but rather, the first row of data (joe james 18 real 14) that should always be pinned as the 1st row (immune to sort), just below the header names.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the Footer you can render the first row within it and then reorder the html:

```
.rt-table > .rt-thead { order: -2 }
.rt-table > .rt-tbody { order: -1 }
.rt-table > .rt-tfoot { order: -2 }
```